# How to see differences between data model versions in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have a few historical data model versions and I would like to view the differences between them. It looks like this was possible in older versions in XCode (it's still documented on the Apple website [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeMappingTool/Articles/xmmDifferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006866-SW1)) but I can't find an equivalent in Xcode 4.5. Is it gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your xcdatamodel files into XML as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875080/convert-core-data-file-from-binary-to-xml) and then compare the XML files directly.

Comment: Thanks, good idea! Not as straightforward as the old XCode-integrated compare but maybe they had good reasons to remove it...